# I can't draw multiple lines in JLabel with mouse listener such as pressed and released

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I can't draw multiple lines on a JLabel which has a picture of a MAP. What I want to do is to draw multiple lines inside that JLabel but it seems that whenever I click/draw a new line, the old line that I've drawn will be deleted. In other words, I want to keep permanent every line that I have drawn. I appreciate your help. Here's my working code (separated main class and gui class).

#### Main class

```
package MP2;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[]args){

JFrame g = new JFrame();
Gui gui = new Gui();


g.setSize(900,650);

g.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
g.add(gui);

g.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

#### GUI class

```
package MP2;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Gui extends JPanel {

private JLabel mousepanel;
private JLabel statusbar;


int x;
int y;
int xx;
int yy;
;
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

public Gui(){

    setLayout(null);


    mousepanel = new JLabel();
    mousepanel.setBounds(20,20,500,450);
    mousepanel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Dm\\Desktop\\Programs\\Dim\\src\\MP2\\mpmap.png"));

    add(mousepanel);

    statusbar = new JLabel();
    statusbar.setBounds(20, 550, 300, 20);
    add(statusbar);


    Handlerclass handlerclass = new Handlerclass();
    mousepanel.addMouseListener(handlerclass);
    mousepanel.addMouseMotionListener(handlerclass);

    }

private class Handlerclass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("clicked at "+ e.getX() +" "+ e.getY());
                    
    
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("you pressed it at" + e.getX() +" and " + e.getY());
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
          
           
        
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("you released the mouse at" + e.getX()+ " and "+ e.getY());
        xx= e.getX();
        yy= e.getY();
    validate();
    repaint();
    
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("you're at "+e.getX()+" and " +e.getY());
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("....");
        mousepanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        
        
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("Dragging at" + e.getX() + " and "+ e.getY());
        
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
        statusbar.setText("moving " + "X = "+e.getX() +" Y = "+e.getY());
    }
    

    
}


public void paint(Graphics g){

 super.paint(g);
 Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
 g2d.setColor(Color.MAGENTA );
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN,1f));


g2d.fillOval(x+15, y+14, 10, 10);
g2d.fillOval(xx+15, yy+15, 10, 10);

g.drawLine(x+20,y+20,xx+20,yy+20);

}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){` In a Swing component such as `JPanel`, override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Learn how to use Layout Managers. There is no need for the validate() on the mouseReleased() event. That method is used when the layout changes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to keep track of all the lines you want to draw. The paint (you probably actually want paintComponent) clears the graphics before you draw on it.

Possible solutions:

1. Keep track of all lines and you want to draw and draw them in the paintComponent.
2. Create a buffer for drawing, draw the lines on this, and when the component ask to be repainted draw the buffer on the graphics in paintComponent.

Comment: +1, See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of each approach.